# error: exec: "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh": stat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: permission denied

Tags: mongodb, docker

When I run: `docker run --name mongodb -p 27107:27107 mongo --noauth --bind_ip=0.0.0.0`

I always get this error: `error: exec: "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh": stat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: permission denied`

and the container gets Exited(1)

I need this to run so that I can link my other docker image to this

I have searched for a solution for this on multiple sites but I haven't found anything. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using some of these flags

```
docker run -itd --name mongodb -p 27107:27107 mongo --noauth --bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I tried this one, still shows the same error through docker logs (containerID).
Also its "mongo" only and not "mongod"

Comment: May be the Image has not been build correctly.
one thing you can do is to make your host's docker-entrypoint.sh executable, chmod +x.

Comment: That's the thing though, I tried that too and:
`chmod: cannot access 'docker-entrypoint.sh': No such file or directory`